# sql command not properly ended (where is my mistakes)

Tags: java, jdbc, insert, oracle-xe, ora-00933

I hope receive my answer this time

i wrote below code but don't know where is my mistake 
it seem correct i think

this code should insert more than million records into oracle xe 
i wrote it by single insert statement when execute PreparedStatement one by one
but it's run took 6 hours !!!!!!
because i was forced use thread.sleep()

```
    package tokenizing;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TokenExtraction2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String myText[]=new String[2276];
        Jdbc db=new Jdbc();
        String st1=null;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        String tokens[][]=new String [3000000][2];
        st1="select ntext from NEWSTEXT ";
        ResultSet result=db.select(st1);
        while(result.next())
        {
            myText[i]=result.getString("ntext");
            ++i;
        }
        db.closedb();
        i=0;
        StringBuilder st= new StringBuilder("insert into tokens5(token,tokenlength) values");
        while(i<2276)
        {

            StringTokenizer s=new StringTokenizer(myText[i]," 0123456789*./»«،~!@#$%^&()_-\"+=:;|<>?“؟”’{}[]‘,\\\t\n\r\fabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ...—`—ـ؛–…_");
            while(s.hasMoreTokens()){
                String key=s.nextToken();
                tokens[j][0]=key;
                tokens[j][1]=(key.length())+"";
                st.append("(?,?)");
                if( i<2276 && s.hasMoreTokens())
                st.append(", ");
                else
                st.append(";");
                //db.insert(st, key, key.length());
                //db.closedb();
                System.out.println(key+"\t");



                   j++;
            }
            System.out.println("num of news is: "+i);
            System.out.println("*****************************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("num of tokens is: "+j);
            System.out.println("next news"+"\t");
            //j=0;

            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(st);
        int k=0;

         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") ;
        Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","ALBALOO","myjava123");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(st.toString());
    //  con.setAutoCommit(false);
        //j=1;
        i=0;
        //j=j-286;
        while(k<j)
        {

            i=i+1;

                ps.setString(i, tokens[k][0]);

            System.out.println(i);
                i=i+1;
                ps.setInt(i,Integer.parseInt(tokens[k][1]));

                System.out.println(k+2);

                k++;


        }

        ps.executeUpdate();
    //con.commit();
}









}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have trying to insert multiple rows with a single `insert` statement, by passing multiple sets of values; `st` appears to end up as:

```
insert into tokens5(token,tokenlength) values (?,?), (?,?);(?,?), ...;`
```

with thousands of value pair placeholder. You can't pass multiple sets of values like that. Oracle isn't expecting a comma after the first `(?,?)`, hence the ORA-00933 error. You also have multiple semi-colons in there as you're putting one for each time around the `i` while loop. As Mark Rotteveel pointed out, you should not have any as Oracle JDBC doesn't allow multiple statements.

You might be better off implementing a string tokenizer as a function on the database and then doing a single `insert ... select from newstext`, rather than pulling all the data out, converting to and pushing it back. You should at least batch up your updates though. You could pass the `tokens` as an array argument to a stored procedure, for example.

I'm struggling to understand what you're really doing though, as it looks like you're splitting a string on pretty much any character, which doesn't leave much for the actual keys, does it? It's hard to follow though...

Comment: you mean in oracle we couldn't insert multiple rows ? i try to do this with batch statement but i was force use thread.sleep again

Comment: Also `;` should not be part of the statement. The semicolon is a statement terminator (and usually only for CLI or script input), most database don't support a `;` as part of the actual statement and the database (or the JDBC driver) will throw an error.

Comment: You aren't inserting multiple rows, you're inserting one row - it's a single `insert` statement. Passing multiple `(?,?)` as part of the `values` clause doesn't make it multi-row. Can you add your actual `st` output (or the start of it anyway) to the question to confirm what I think you're doing?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - good point, it's probably tripping over that first. And it's getting one `;` for each time round the loop, too.

Comment: i use below  link code plz look at code http://brian.pontarelli.com/2011/06/21/jdbc-batch-vs-multi-row-inserts/

Comment: thanks friends , i could run my program without any errors & exceptions. i used batch as Alex mentioned it in his guide  . I want to preprocess news texts  that tokenizing is one of it's stages.

Comment: @sara - that's good news. Curious about the performance improvement! Please remember to mark Mark's answer as accepted.

Comment: using batch  cause to enhance   performance of my code . ( 6 hours --->> 120 seconds !!!!!!!!!!!!!!) that's great .  without using batch  i was forced to run a loop like this....> while(i<1200000){ insert into my table ; thread.sleep(100); i++;}. thanks Alex and other Professional friends .

Comment: i'd like  but i have no Permission for chat :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Oracle [INSERT description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2163698) in the SQL Language Reference, then you can see that Oracle does not support inserting multiple rows using `VALUES`. Also as I commented above, using `;` in a query doesn't always work as it is usually not part of the query itself, but a terminator for command line or script input.

In your specific case you are even trying to put multiple statements into one prepare. In JDBC a single statement prepare (or execute) should only be one actual statement, not multiple statements separated by `;`. Drivers (or the database) usually don't allow it, although some provide options to execute multiple statements, but that is not compliant with JDBC.

Instead you can use JDBC batched updates:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
try (
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.
         prepareStatement("insert into tokens5(token,tokenlength) values (?, ?)"
) {
    // I use tokens as an abstraction on how you get the token and its length
    while (tokens.next()) {
        pstmt.setString(1, tokens.token());
        pstmt.setInt(2, tokens.length());
        pstmt.addBatch();
    };
    pstmt.executeBatch();
    // Optionally do something with result of executeBatch()
    con.commit();
}
```

Depending on the database+driver this will have similar runtime performance as a multi-values insert (I believe with Oracle it does), or simply behave as if you executed a single PreparedStatement multiple times with different values.

Comment: what 's size of batch in oracle xe ?

Comment: The batch is - afaik - with Oracle as big as you make it. Oracle gives the [advice](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm) to use sizes between 50 and 100 to limit memory consumption in the driver (note that article talks about 'standard' JDBC batching and about a specific Oracle batching feature that is disabled by default and that I recommend you don't use). Also: do you really think you need to worry about this?

Comment: ya , because when in bit of time i send  many request to oracle-xe ( in my laptop 80 request ) i get "ORA-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found.

Cause: The listener could not find any available service handlers that are appropriate for the client connection."  i was forced to use thread.sleep

Comment: one question arised in my mind : why doesn't  oracle  allow to users to insert/update multiple rows by single statement like my-sql ?

Comment: I can't speak for Oracle's design decisions, but I guess it is because Oracle has batched updates built into its wire protocol, so there is no real need for multi-values inserts.

Comment: I use a if expression when  run " pstmt.executeBatch();" i said if ( i%1000==0 )  pstmt.executeBatch();